# Can't find where form is processed?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress theme that i want to customize and i cannot find where the custom post type `Services` form $_POST values are processed.  The form action returns to the same page but when looking at the page and the wrapper page, i cannot see any functions that process $_POST values?

Here is the form action

```
<form id="edit-service" class="edit-service" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://example.com/add-service/?step=edit-info&amp;hash=427d72b2fe6d0e70a9cb" novalidate="novalidate"></form>
```

How do i debug this to find where $_POST values are being processed?

Comment: Well, `action` of form points into `http://example.com/add-service/` url.

Comment: I've checked, no $_POST values being processed.

Comment: need more codes to analyse, e.g. the code for $_GET['step']=="edit-info" if there is any

Comment: i can't even find that either. Is there a way to check the functions being run on the page?

Comment: cant help without seeing the code

Comment: Is there a way i can stop the form processing?  Like `break;` the page and not redirect?

Comment: if you want to stop after submit, just at the beginning `add-service ` page very first line, type if($_POST){ print_r($_POST);exit;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the add-service (controller?) you can either do the following:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

If you are using firefox you could also use the [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) extension, which let's you view and edit all POST data.

Answer (score 0):

This will be bit tricky to find, you can try searching for something like $_POST['edit-info'] or $_REQUEST['edit-info'] in entire code, use eclipse IDE, Press ctrl + h and search for above, it will help you